# Why is this recursive regex not working?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a simple regex to match nested curly brackets. So if I have this text:

```
{
  apple
  {second}
  banana
}
```

Then I want it to match the entire text between the first and last `{}` (including the 2nd pair of `{}`). Here's the regex I've written:

```
/{ (?:.+?|(?R) ) }/six
```

The output for this is:

```
{ apple {second}
```

As you can see the first curly bracket is being matched, and the 'banana' at the end is not being matched. Here's the output I want it to return:

```
apple {second} banana
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to match the entire inside, or do you want to match the inside as 3 separate tokens?

Comment: @Corbin The entire inside as one string/token.

Comment: Seems like you don't need regex then?  Just strip off the first/last characters.  Or am I missing something?  If you needed to make sure the braces were there, you could check the first and last characters explicitly, or use a simple pattern like `{(.+)}`

Comment: @Corbin Yes, you are missing something. The string I've posted is just a part of a larger text, so I need to use regex to parse it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you want to use is:

```
/{ (?:  (?R) | .+? )+ }/six
```

With your regex, the `.+?` would have always taken precedence. PCRE would match the longest possible string and never look for the alternative.

Only making the alternative `(..)+` repetetive allows the matching to switch between the recursive part and the match-anything placeholder.

Comment: Have you tried running this regex? When I run it as is, my apache always crashes.

Comment: What's the `+` after the last `)` for? It seems to be the culprit and crashes apache, when I remove it then the regex doesn't capture correctly{}, but doesn't crash.

Comment: Backtracking limit. Just tested on CLI. You might try to use `[^{}]+` in place of the `.+?` though.

Comment: That worked. But its matching the full text instead of just the stuff inside the first set of brackets. Output: `{
            apple
            {second}
            banana
        }`

Comment: That's what it is supposed to do. It always returns the complete match; only asserts the structure within, no cutting out.

Comment: I need to extract the string between the first and last curly brackets, not only assert the structure.

Comment: I need to extract the complete inner block of text between the first curly brackets. This is the output I need: `apple {second} banana`. So I need the inner brackets returned as well.

Comment: Aha. How about just adding a capture group then?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`\{([\s\S]*)\}`

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to do it via `(?R)` as I'm trying to learn how that works too. Can you tell me what's wrong with my earlier regex?